# Azure App insight difference between response times HTTP & first dependency logged in the appservice

Tags: .net, azure, http

Recently we have been using appinsights to monitor our application response time between various parts of code as oppose to manual logging. But something I have been always been confused with is the metrics and results which are shown in each Transaction.[image]
As we can see the highlighted area are various event timings.

There is always some lost time between Event time for when HTTP event logs and when it reaches to server dependency and the first DB call.
The above example is just one of fastest ones I noticed but there are various slow ones where HTTP call to First DB hit in that services takes > 5seconds of delay.

Another slower example : [image]

Comment: anyone ? I still like to understand this more any reference would be helpful..